# how to pass javascript variables value to backend node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How to show value of state and city variable made in javascript here in html code and later send to database

this code is saving correct location details in these 2 variables state and city, now I want to use these 2 variables state and city on in my html code and send these values to backend

```js
let places, input, address, city;
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function() {
  var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("searchTextField"))
  google.maps.event.addListener(places, "place_changed", function() {
    var place = places.getPlace();

    var address = place.formatted_address;
    var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var geocoder = (geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder());
    geocoder.geocode({
      latLng: latlng
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[0]) {
          var address = results[0].formatted_address;
          var pin = results[0].address_components[results[0].address_components.length - 1].long_name;
          const country = results[0].address_components[results[0].address_components.length - 2].long_name;
          const state = results[0].address_components[results[0].address_components.length - 3].long_name;
          const city = results[0].address_components[results[0].address_components.length - 5].long_name; 
          console.log(state)
          console.log(city) 
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<section class="section-hero section">
  <form class="hero-form" action="/search" method="POST">
    <div class="search-box location-box ">
      <input type="text" class="location-bar" id="searchTextField" placeholder="Location" />
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: I also tried to send these value using ${city} and ${state} yet it is not working

Comment: How do you communicate with the backend?
did you try to define a route in the backend and send the variables using it ?

Comment: Generally either by making an AJAX request or a form POST...

Comment: You need the google api script in the head BEFORE your script. Also I removed the invalid `</input>` in the snippet I made you

Comment: Change `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function() {` to `window.adddEventListner("DOMContentLoaded", function() {`

Comment: yess I've back end connected and also I'm able to pass other input values that I'm getting on page to back end but I don't know how to pass these 2 value city and state that i'm generating in script